# How to enable Dark theme for iOS 12 and lower

Tags: swift, uikit, darkmode

I have already added support for iOS13 where there are two switches: first one for the automatic, system based theme and the other switch to turn on and off dark theme and am switching it with the given method:

```
func changeThemeTo(theme: String){
        switch theme {
        case "dark":
            UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        case "light":
            UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        case "auto":
            UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        default: break
        }
}
```

And everything is working fine for iOS 13, but now I need to enable this to work for iOS lower than 13. Is there something I can do similar to `window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` or should I completely change the switching logic as did on https://www.onswiftwings.com/posts/dark-mode/

Comment: Dark mode is not supported before iOS 13. If dark mode isn't essential, just defaulting to light mode & disabling the button to change mode would probably be easiest.

Comment: But dark mode is essential. Is my only solution to do as said on OnSwiftWings link?

Comment: @noimagination yes, you have to do it manually